# Universal Link and App Store Redirection Issue on iOS, using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-cloud-functions, ios-universal-links

I have a Firebase Cloud Functions implementation to open Amazon product links inside the Amazon app on Android/iOS devices or redirect users to the Amazon app on App Store if the app is not installed. While this works flawlessly on Android, I encounter a problem on iOS.

The issue on iOS is that when the Amazon app is installed, the Universal Link opens the app correctly but simultaneously redirects users to the App Store as well. This behavior is unintended and confusing for users.

Below is the relevant code snippet used in the Firebase Cloud Functions:

```
const htmlResponse = `
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script>
              function openApp(){
                  setTimeout(function () {
                      window.location.href = '${urls.redirectUrl}';
                      setTimeout(function () {
                          window.location.href = '${urls.fallbackUrl}';
                      }, 555);
                  }, 10);
              }
              openApp();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
`;

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.send(htmlResponse);
```

As far as I tried to fix it, it looks like some issue with the browser.
On Android devices, using Chrome when the line

`window.location.href = '${urls.redirectUrl}';`

executes, and the redirects happen (redirects that basically open the Amazon mobile app), the control has been shifted from the browser to the mobile OS, so the next code

```
setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = '${urls.fallbackUrl}';
}, 555);
```

doesn't executes.

But this isn't happening on iOS. When my link is opened in Safari, both redirects happen.

First Redirect: Opens the Amazon App
Second Redirect: (Fallback basically): Open the Amazon App in App Store.
Which basically I don't want, because the first redirect was successful.

To resolve my problem, so far I tried to implement some JavaScipt listener, to detect if the first redirect happens or not.

Like

> document.hidden

> window.addEventListener('blur', function () {});

> window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function () {});

but none of it helped me to overcome this problem.

Comment: Hi! This seems some kind of recently added popup blocking mechanism or iOS issue (since 2020). It's also mentioned here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734266  . I;m struggling with similar issue. If use link without setTimeout I don;t have issue with redirect. Once I use something larger than 900ms delay - it stops working. So meanwhile I have applied 900ms delay and will try to with it. But this is really strange...